# Divs won't react to my padding/margin

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I've been trying to make a good looking div (just a normal div that acts like the content of the website)

It would look similar to a typical "news" link. The width is 80%. The image should be on the left side with a border, a header about the current news, a paragraph which ends with a link to the rest and then using the hr tag to finish it and start over with the next news..

So the first problem is that I can't use margin or padding to let the text be away from the border of the image. The header and paragraph starts exactly where the image border ends, no matter how much I tried. The second problem is that when I used the hr tag, it starts where the paragraph ends..

The third problem is that when I use the display inline-block tag, the margin auto won't work any more, it's all floated to the left.

Here is my code:

```css
div.content1 {
  width: 80%;
  color: white;
  background: #2B2B2B;
  margin-top: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px #3A3A3A;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

div.content1>img {
  float: left;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.content1>p {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content1">
  <img src="Twitter.png">
  <h1> Welcome! </h1>
  <p>Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... </p>
  <hr>
  <h1> Welcome! </h1>
  <p>Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding a margin-right or padding-right to the image.

Comment: margin solved most of the part, had to put in styles directly into the html code and use both br and hr code but works pretty well atm

Answer (score 0):

Adding `margin-right` would solve your first issue. For issue 2, you need to clear the float you have assigned to `img` tag. And obviously you need to get rid of `display:inline-block` to make `margin:auto` work. Try this code.

```
<div class="content1">
  <img src="Twitter.png">
  <h1> Welcome! </h1>
  <p>Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... </p>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <hr>
  <h1> Welcome! </h1>
  <p>Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... Long followed text... </p>
</div>

div.content1 {
  width: 80%;
  color: white;
  background: #2B2B2B;
  margin-top: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px #3A3A3A;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

div.content1>img {
  float: left;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.content1>p {}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```